# Porting an app developed with Android SDK to codenameone

Tags: codenameone

How would one go about porting an app built with Android SDK to Codenameone? The objective is to port to multiple OS.

Comment: If the app works as intended, what is the benefit of porting?

Comment: Support for iOS and other platforms is the main benefit for a Codename One port...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking out the Android trail in the Codename One website http://codenameone.com/android.html generally you would need to rewrite your UI and networking code. Adapt to a smaller subset of Java functionality etc.

You could keep most of the business logic intact though. I would suggest starting with a GUI builder application and some of the [How Do I?](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i.html) tutorials just to get the UI right then the rest should be easy.